# Is it enough to authorise only $connect rout in api gateway websockets?

Tags: security, websocket, jwt, aws-api-gateway

I am using websocket api powered by api gateway and lambdas. I need to implement custom authoriser (i.e. lambda function that checks user token created by our custom solution).

Am I correct that I only need to authorise `$connect` request and assume that all subsequent messages and disconnect requests are secure and coming from same user?

I was trying to think of the drawbacks here and only one I came up with is that our tokens are short lived i.e. they expire and renew after 15min and we can have cases in the app where users are connected longer than that.

So in theory weed need to authorize all messages, but this seems counter productive and costly.

Comment: You are correct, only the $connect route needs to have authorization enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it appears safe to assume that all requests from a single WebSocket are coming from a single client. In fact, the connection closes if the browser closes. If one of the requests is authorized, should be good.

Add a logger to default $disconnect (via a simple lambda or directly) to get a better picture.

I will be able to comment better on the token part if I was aware of how/when tokens are generated and used.
If your other functions fail because the token has expired, you may want to return the appropriate response so that you simply log out from UI rather than failing.

You may want to put a token renewal mechanism in place at the front end so that the active user always has a valid token.